# Call can throw, but errors can not be thrown out of a global variable initializer

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using Xcode 7 beta and after migrating to Swift 2 I experienced some issues with this line of code:

```
let recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
```

I get an error saying "Call can throw, but errors can not be thrown out of a global variable initializer".
My app relies on the `recorder` to be a global variable. Is there a way to keep it global but fix these issues? I have no need for advanced error handling, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you know that your function call will not throw an exception, you can call the throwing function with `try!` to disable error propagation. Note that this will throw a runtime exception if an error is actually thrown.

```
let recorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
```

[Source: Apple Error Handling documentation (Disabling Error Propagation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID512)

Answer (score 15):

There are 3 ways that you can use to solve this problem.

- Creating optional AVAudioRecorder using try?
- If you know that it will return you AVRecorder, you can implicity use try!
- Or then handle the error using try / catch

**Using try?**

```
// notice that it returns AVAudioRecorder?
if let recorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings) { 
    // your code here to use the recorder
}
```

**Using try!**

```
// this is implicitly unwrapped and can crash if there is problem with soundFileURL or recordSettings
let recorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
```

**try / catch**

```
// The best way to do is to handle the error gracefully using try / catch
do {
    let recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
} catch {
    print("Error occurred \(error)")
}
```