# Call can throw, but errors cannot be thrown out of a property initializer

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsfilemanager

After updated to Swift 2.0, when `NSFielManager` is called, it has caused the following error. Could you tell me what is the problem?

```
let cachesDirectoryURL = NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
```

Error:

> "Call can throw, but errors cannot be thrown out of a property
> initializer"

Comment: *Search* for error messages - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776458/call-can-throw-but-errors-can-not-be-thrown-out-of-a-global-variable-initialize , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786877/avaudioplayer-no-longer-working-in-swift-2-0-xcode-7-beta There is nothing 'special' with this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which means we have to catch the error that might be thrown, should problem occurs:

```
do
{
    let cachesDirectoryURL = try NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: This still 'throws the error' out of the *property* initializer - and is otherwise invalid in context. The `let` in this case refers to a member, as indicated by the message, not a local binding.

Comment: It must be 1) a property, and; 2) under Swift 2 to reproduce the OPs behavior. This code makes no sense in context of *property* declarations.

Comment: @Unheilig http://swiftstub.com/601877219/ - context is wrong for the reported error. If you can show this working for a *property* created in the `do`..

Comment: First off, I am not angry. Secondly, I downvoted precisely because the *provided example* disagrees with this answer. If a counter example (or correction) to the code is provided to show the case (and that a *property* is created), I will reverse the downvote as shown it would be shown to be incorrect. Answers that "work" but do not correctly address the issue are still wrong; this answer is not the only one I have downvoted even though it "works".

Comment: I have not 'lashed out'. There is no point to make this personal. I've taken time to provide a counter example. As long as it stands I cannot accept such an answer as valid, "works" or not.

Answer (score 12):

If you are declaring this as global in a class you need to add prefix "try!" to value you are assigning.

like this

```
let cachesDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
```